# Filtrar para obtener el mayor dato por fecha

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo la siguiente tabla:

```
 id    n1   n2       fecha
1181    1   26      2019-02-03
1183    1   20,9    2019-02-03
1185    1   20      2019-02-04
1187    1   21,7    2019-02-04
1189    1   22      2019-02-04
1191    1   22,5    2019-02-04
1193    1   20      2019-02-04
1195    1   22,9    2019-02-04
1197    1   22,8    2019-02-04
1199    1   22,8    2019-02-04
1201    1   22,6    2019-02-04
1203    1   22,5    2019-02-05
1205    1   22,4    2019-02-05
1207    1   22,6    2019-02-05
1209    1   21      2019-02-05
1211    1   19,8    2019-02-05
1213    1   21,8    2019-02-05
1215    1   22,3    2019-02-05
1217    1   21      2019-02-05
1219    1   22,8    2019-02-05
1221    1   23,1    2019-02-05
1223    1   21,3    2019-02-05
1225    1   21,9    2019-02-05
1227    1   21,7    2019-02-05
1229    1   22,9    2019-02-05
1231    1   22,8    2019-02-05
1233    1   22,7    2019-02-05
```

Necesito filtrar la tabla para que en cada fecha me entregue únicamente el valor de n2 mayor, es decir, en este ejemplo seria:

```
    1181    1   26      2019-02-03
    1195    1   22,9    2019-02-04
    1221    1   23,1    2019-02-05
```

He intentado con:

```
SELECT n2, fecha 
FROM dbo.tabla
WHERE id= '1'
GROUP BY n2, fecha
ORDER BY fecha ASC, n2 DESC
```

Pero con esto solo he logrado ordenarla, sin éxito en el filtro que deseo, me podrían ayudar por favor?

Les agradezco

Comment: Averigua sobre la función **MAX** de SQL

Comment: y de paso, lee bien lo que hace group by...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intenta esta forma:

```
SELECT MAX(n2) AS Dato, fecha 
FROM dbo.tabla
WHERE id = '1'
GROUP BY fecha
ORDER BY fecha ASC, n2 DESC
```